# Javascript - insert copied text without containing box

Tags: javascript, html, copy, textarea

I'm currently learning Javascript and face the following problem. I want to copy the text of a readonly html textarea and use the following code:

```
function copy_text ()
{
    var text = document.getElementById("textbox");
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(text);
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

Actually it works, but there is a little quirk. If I insert the copied text to another input field, for example like the input line of a webbrowser, then the text appears perfectly fine as text. However, if I paste the text into Microsoft Word, the text appears in a box with two slides, one at the bottom and one at the left side. What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're selecting the entire node, which is a `textarea`, so that's what gets copied to the clipboard. Word is then pasting a `textarea` into the document.

If you just want the text of the `textarea`, just use its `select` method:

```js
function copy_text() {
  var text = document.getElementById("textbox");
  text.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
}
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", copy_text, false);
```

```html
<textarea id="textbox" readonly>Some example text</textarea>
<br><input type="button" id="btn" value="Copy">
```

`select` selects the *contents* of the textarea, not the textarea itself.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I intended. Just one little question: what does false mean in the eventListener?

Comment: @AlexM: See [`addEventListener` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). It's optional now (with the default being `false`), but didn't used to be. Here in 2017, you're safe leaving it off. When IE got `addEventListener` (in IE9), they made it optional, and Chrome's always made it optional. Firefox made it optional in v6. It's even optional in old Android browsers. So yeah, I should just stop putting it on there. :-)

Comment: Ok, so I will leave it off. I've just tried the very same thing that you've written above for deleting text. Exactly the same function, the only change being document.execCommand("delete"). Copying text works fine, however, trying to delete it with the same code does not work. Instead, the whole text in the textarea gets selected (this typical blue background), but it isn't deleted. Why is that? I think it should actually be supposed to work.

Comment: @AlexM: I have no idea, but that's a different question. But note that if you want to remove the `textarea`, use `text.parentNode.removeChild(text)` (or `text.remove()` on newer browsres). If you want to clear it, use `text.value = "";` No need for `execCommand`.